# append a list into a file in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to append a list into a file. This is my code:

```
test= open("test.txt", 'a')
for word in list:
    test.write(word)
test.close()
```

When I run this, I get a "TypeError: expected a character buffer object" error.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your list contains non-string elements. `file.write()` accepts only string arguments. Use `str()` function to convert the list elements into strings.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're writing an encoded string to the file. You probably want to print new lines as well:

```
test= open("test.txt", 'a')
for word in list:
    test.write(bytes(str(word) + '\n', 'utf-8'))
test.close()
```

Comment: Should now do that now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your list must have elements of type str or you can cast it to str before write.